# Return not in function

Tags: javascript, firebug

Firebug is reporting a "return not in function" error with no location (well, line 1 of nothing).  How can I track down the source of this error?

```
return not in function
[Break on this error] return(0)
javascript:return... (line 1)
```

I'm running FireBug  1.05 on FF 2.0.0.20 on Ubuntu.

I found a **solution** that works (for this configuration):

```
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href='/';
  if (childSummary.more) {
    link.onclick = capture(function(id) { follow(id); }, childSummary.id);
  } else {
    link.onclick = capture(function(id) { show(id); }, childSummary.id);
  }
  link.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
  div.appendChild(link);

  [...]

 function capture(fn, val) {
   return function() { fn(val); return false; };
 }
```

The code was in a loop in which the id was changing, necessitating the capture function.

Formerly the href was 'javascript: return 0' and the capture function wasn't returning false directly, instead using the result of the fn, and there was a path when it was returning the equivalent of true.  The href was being evaluated causing the error.

Defining href as '#' or '' caused all the links to appear as already visited.  Not defining href at all caused there to be no link highlighting.  This seemed simplest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the "javascript:return ..." is telling.  I believe you're trying to return a value in the `href` attribute of an anchor, as below:

```
<a href="javascript: return false">Test</a>
```

The reason Firebug isn't telling you the location is because it's not in any JavaScript, but is rather in a one-liner in the DOM.

Comment: Looks like it.  I'm using javascript to generate a link with an onclick function, and setting the href attribute of the link.  The onclick function returns false at the end of its operation and I thought this would prevent the href from being evaluated.  Since this just started failing I'm wondering if something earlier in the onclick function is behaving differently.

Comment: Could we see the exact code for your link?  "Return false" is okay inside of an onclick; it stops the href from being evaluated.  But if you're using it this way, the href itself ought to be a URL, not more JS.

Comment: This is a good explanation for how to use onclick to prevent anchors from being loaded: http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/#onclick

Comment: Thanks - this post will helpful to me too. And that link is really good as well!

Answer (score 4):

Javascript returns an error because the return statement is not inside a function. A possible cause for this is incorrect function definition, such as:

```
myFunc() { some code; return; }
```

where the correct code definition is:

```
function myFunc() { some code; return; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to hazard a guess that this means you have an extra closing brace, or a missing opening brace.

Is your codebase prohibitively large to do a spot check around each of your return functions?  Do you have an IDE that highlights matching braces for you?

Answer (score 0):

I got this when typing into the console window in firebug.
I'd written a for loop to search for something in a list
dont try and return a value in there - just assign it to a variable and you can see the object/value in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Lew has the answer for dougfelt, but others who get this error should also look out for any return statement that doesn't reside in a function. For instance:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("I'm JavaScript!");
    return false;
</script>
```

`return false;` is outside of any function, and will cause this error.