# getting error code "SyntaxError: return not in function", can't figure out why

Tags: javascript

I just started learning JS on codecademy and I'm in the middle of a tutorial that has me make a rock, paper, scissors game.

So far everything has been going well, but I just got to this if/else if/else bit in the code and I can't quite seem to get it.

My code:

```
/*var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}*/
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1===choice2);
    return "The result is a tie!";
    };
if (choice1==="rock") {
    if (choice2==="scissors") {
        return "rock wins";
    } else {
        return "paper wins";
    }
}
```

I've tried it both with the top code commented out as well as active, and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: if (choice1===choice2) try removing semicolon after this

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error.

Comment: Yeah, ironically this syntax error is pretty self explanatory... return isn't in a function, because you used a semicolon where you need an open-brace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return not in function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795337/return-not-in-function)

Comment: It also would mean that the function doesn't expect return value and you've mentioned return value particularly like 'return false;'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `{` after your first `if()`:

```
if (choice1===choice2);
    return "The result is a tie!";
};
```

should be:

```
if (choice1===choice2) {
    return "The result is a tie!";
}
```

and also one at the end of your function (once you get this fixed)

Comment: ok, now I'm having another problem... I fixed the {} issue, but the error that I'm getting now states;

 "Oops, try again. Your code returned 'The result is a tie!' instead of 'paper wins' when the inputs are rock and paper "
  help?

Comment: Glad I could help! If this did answer your question, don't forget to check the mark beside it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2)
{
    if (choice1 === choice2)
    {return "The result is a tie!";}

    if (choice1 === "rock") 

    if (choice2 === "scissors")
    {return "rock wins";}

    else 
    {return "paper wins";}
};
```

I got this and it worked.